# jqGrid - Modify cell data before insertion

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an array of objects that are returned from a service. I'm providing this array to the `data` hash of `jqGrid` and setting its datatype to `local`. I have a property called `Pricing` and its value is an object with properties `Currency` and `Price`.

Now I need to concatenate these two properties and return the result. I know I can access this nested structure using `jsonmap` and a few old threads on stackoverflow suggested that `jsonmap` hash can also be a function. However, according to the documentation ([jqGrid ColModel docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options)), `jsonmap` accepts only a string and my output also just renders [object object] when I try to assign it to a function. May be the old method doesn't work anymore.

```
{
    name: 'Pricing', jsonmap: function (item) {
        return (item.Price + ' ' + item.Currency).toString();
    }, index: 'Pricing', width: 90, sorttype: "int"
}
```

Sample data:

```
model = [
    {
        Id: 2,
        PropertyCode: 'Ref 306',
        Pricing: {
            Currency: 'AUD',
            Price: '$500000'
        }
    }
];
```

My question is, is there any way to do this computation before I pass the value to jqGrid? I know I can do this computation outside on the entire model and then pass it.

Comment: Could you include an example of the input data? You wrote about "insertion" of the data. Do you mean initial filling of data or inserting of data during editing of grid?

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for your time. I meant the initial filling of data. I just added a sample object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `jsonmap` will be not used in case of `datatype: "local"`. If you use `datatype: "local"` and `data` parameter then you can **directly** provide array with items of data for jqGrid. It's not a real problem to make a loop where you fill new empty array with the data required by jqGrid.

If you still want to use your original data as the input for jqGrid you can use `datatype: "jsonstring"` which is very close to `datatype: "local"`. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jsonmapWithLocalData.htm) shows how you can use it. The demo uses the following code:

```
var mydata = [
        {
            Id: 2,
            PropertyCode: 'Ref 306',
            Pricing: {
                Currency: 'AUD',
                Price: '$500000'
            }
        }
    ];

$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    datastr: mydata,
    jsonReader: {
        id: "Id",
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        repeatitems: false
    },
    colModel: [
        { name: "PropertyCode", width: 110 },
        { name: "Pricing", width: 90,
            jsonmap: function (item) {
                return (item.Pricing.Price + ' ' + item.Pricing.Currency).toString();
            }}
    ],
    rowNum: 10000,
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: "auto"
});
```

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate your help.